# VBA Class properties returning empty strings

Tags: vba, class

I am trying to create a class in VBA for the first time. I have looked up some solutions and I don't see anything wrong with my class, but when I run the test code, the integer returns correctly but the strings return empty:

Class

```
Property Let Name(strName As String)
    pName = strName
End Property
Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property
Property Let Class(strClass As String)
    pClass = strClass
End Property
Property Get Class() As String
    Class = pClass
End Property
Property Let Aggro(intAggro As Integer)
    pAggro = intAggro
End Property
Property Get Aggro() As Integer
    Aggro = pAggro
End Property
```

Test Procedure

```
Sub ClassTest()
    Dim Dog1 As New Critter

    Dog1.Name = "Labrador"
    Dog1.Class = "Canine"
    Dog1.Aggro = 0     

    Debug.Print Dog1.Name  'returns ""
    Debug.Print Dog1.Class  'returns ""
    Debug.Print Dog1.Aggro  'returns 0  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you have wrong is you haven't define private variables to hold your property values. It appears the integer is working because Integer initializes to 0, and you are 'setting' the value to 0. Just add this to the top of your class and try again:

```
Private pName as String
Private pClass as String
Private pAggro as Integer
```

:D