# Excel VBA Class Property returning a public long variable, but not a public string variable

Tags: oop, excel, vba

this my first ever experience with an object orientated approach: hope so will help my. (and found this, which seemed helpful, but I dont's see it anyway: [Excel Class properties returning empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095488/excel-class-properties-returning-empty-strings)

First: what do I want? A class for importing a table and having a means to sort and filter (and more manipulation) of/by certain columns in it. The position, if not the name, of the columns may vary from time to time.

Second: This my class: (excerpt)
    Option Explicit

```
Private ColNumber_ As Long
Private ColTxt_ As String
Private blnVis As Boolean
Private blnSort As Boolean
Private sCrit As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   blnVis = True
   blnSort = False
   ColTxt_ = ""
End Sub

Public Sub initCols(ColTxt_ As String)
   Dim rng As Range
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Glasliste").Range("Tabelle1[#Headers]").Select
   Set rng = Selection.Find(What:=ColTxt_, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
     LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
     MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'After:=ActiveCell,
   MsgBox rng.Text ' This gives me the desired text, however I cannot use it outside of the class
   MsgBox rng.Column
   ColNumber_ = rng.Column
   ColTxt_ = rng.Text
End Sub

'Get the text of the header
Public Property Get ColTxt() As String 'Optional lngOrder As Long
   ColTxt = ColTxt_
End Property

'Get the position of the Column
Public Property Get ColNumber() As Long 'Optional lngOrder As Long
   ColNumber = ColNumber_
End Property
```

Third: this is my code (excerpt):

```
Sub initSpalten()
   Dim Typ As clsSpalte: Set Typ = New clsSpalte: Typ.initCols ("Typ")
   MsgBox Typ.ColTxt ' Here I get an empty string
   Dim Aufbau As clsSpalte: Set Aufbau = New clsSpalte: Aufbau.initCols ("Aufbau")
   MsgBox Aufbau.ColNumber ' I here get the right number... but dont see any difference?
End Sub
```

Fourth: My question, or what I do not understand:
with the above MsgBox, commented "Here I get an empty string" my code later will not work. I do need this text. I cannot assign the corresponding private variable directly. However, why does it work with the long "Aufbau.ColNumber" ?
Sure this is not such a mystery for some of you? (hopefully)... Any help very much appreciated!
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ColTxt_` variable is "ghosting" the class member variable with the same name. Try changing:

```
'                   vvv
Public Sub initCols(txt As String)
   Dim rng As Range
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Glasliste").Range("Tabelle1[#Headers]").Select
'                                 vvv 
   Set rng = Selection.Find(What:=txt, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
     LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
     MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'After:=ActiveCell,
   MsgBox rng.Text ' This gives me the desired text, however I cannot use it outside of the class
   MsgBox rng.Column
   ColNumber_ = rng.Column
   ColTxt_ = rng.Text
End Sub
```